# Calling python from django subprocess, mysql not found error

Tags: python, mysql, django, subprocess, pymysql

1. python dbtest1.py  ==> work O.K.

```
       dbtest1.py :<br>
       import pymysql.connector<br>
       dbCon = pymysql.connector.connect(host='...', database='...', user='...', password='...')<br>
       cursor = dbCon.cursor()<br>
       cursor.execute("INSERT INTO cm_person (name) VALUES ('고길송')")<br>
       dbCon.commit()
```

2. access from Django using subprocess, Not found error...

```
   views.py include...

    def datatest(request):<br>
       subprocess.call(['python', 'dbtest3.py'])<br>
       return HttpResponse('Call python...')
```

**Error message;**

```
     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'
```

Did I miss something? or is there any other methods?
Thank you.

Comment: subprocess.call(['python', 'dbtest1.py'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using virtual environments, depending how you run your script, `'python'` might refer to the system Python. Using `sys.executable` instead of `'python'` might help.

Note that if you are using WSGI, `sys.executable` is probably not set correctly, so you might want to set it explicitly in your WSGI entry point script.

Answer (score 0):

views.py

def datatest(request):
   subprocess.call([sys.executable, "-c", "import dbtest2"])
   return HttpResponse('Call python...')